# How can I check does my ios8 custom keyboard extension have open access?

Tags: ios, ios8, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard

In my ios 8 keyboard extension I wanna check did user gave my keyboard open access or not. But I couldn't find any API. Swiftkey and other custom keyboards somehow solve that problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no API, but if you have app group access enabled, you can try to check if you are able to read/write to the folder. It should give you a permission error access is not enabled.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is an easier way (no need to create a container):

```
- (BOOL) isOpenAccessGranted
{
    if ([UIPasteboard generalPasteboard])
        return YES;

    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this,

```
-(BOOL)isOpenAccessGranted
{
      NSFileManager *filemanager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
      NSString *containerPath = [[filemanager containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"/***YOUR APP GROUP ID***/"] path];

      NSError *err;

      [filemanager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:containerPath error:&err];

      if(err != nil)
      {
           NSLog(@"Full Access: Off");
           return NO;
      }

      NSLog(@"Full Access On");
      return YES;
}
```

Comment: some more details:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25472388/how-to-check-the-allow-full-access-is-enabled-in-ios-8

Answer (score 1):

Pasteboard API changed in iOS10 beta

Swift:

```
func isOpenAccessGranted() -> Bool {
    let originalString = UIPasteboard.general.string
    UIPasteboard.general.string = "TEST"
    if UIPasteboard.general.hasStrings {
        UIPasteboard.general.string = originalString
        return true
    }else{
        return false
    }
}
```

Found this live-saving answer here

[How to check the "Allow Full Access" is enabled in iOS 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25472388/how-to-check-the-allow-full-access-is-enabled-in-ios-8)

I tested a few apps and works perfect!

Comment: any reason for downvote? if there's something wrong here would be good if you could explain..

Comment: awesome, @Drico

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to check your custom keyboard extension have open access or not:

```
func isOpenAccessGranted() -> Bool{
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
       let originalString = UIPasteboard.general.string
       UIPasteboard.general.string = "Sour LeangChhean"

       if UIPasteboard.general.hasStrings {

           UIPasteboard.general.string = originalString ?? ""
           return true
       }else{
           UIPasteboard.general.string = ""
           return false
       }
  } else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
       if UIPasteboard.general.isKind(of: UIPasteboard.self) {
           return true
       }else{
           return false
       }
   }
}
```