# Check full access for custom keyboard extension ipad

Tags: ios, ipad, keyboard

I need to know whether allow full access has been toggle on or off for my keyboard extension.  Following the answer in this: [Check full access for custom keyboard extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26072140/1522113) I was able to get the check to work reliably for an iPhone but on an iPad (iPad 3 device) or any iPad simulators iOS 8.1 this always returns false.

Here is the code I am using from the above referenced SO answer:

```
-(BOOL)isOpenAccessGranted{

    NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *containerPath = [[fm containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"mygrouppath"] path];

    NSError *err;

    [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:containerPath error:&err];

    if(err != nil){
        NSLog(@"Full Access: Off");
        return NO;
    }

    NSLog(@"Full Access On");
    return YES;
}
```

How do i get reliable results on an iPad?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution.  Checking if the general pasteboard is available seems to be a very reliable way of checking if full access is on.

```
-(BOOL)isOpenAccessGranted{

    UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
    NSLog(@"pasteboard: %@", pasteboard);
    if(pasteboard){
        NSLog(@"Full Access On");
        return YES;
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Full Access: Off");
        return NO;
    }
}
```