# How to check allow full access for custom keyboard extension from container app?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, custom-keyboard

I have tried to check allow full access for keyboard extension from container app but not getting a reliable solution.

I have tried below methods:

[Check full access for custom keyboard extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26072140/check-full-access-for-custom-keyboard-extension)

[Check full access for custom keyboard extension ipad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27466478/check-full-access-for-custom-keyboard-extension-ipad)

[Check full access for custom keyboard extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26072140/check-full-access-for-custom-keyboard-extension)

[Check full access for custom keyboard extension ipad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27466478/check-full-access-for-custom-keyboard-extension-ipad)

None of the above solution work for container app.

Comment: Are you testing on simulator or iPhone device ?

Comment: I am testing in a device.

Comment: did you find a solution yet?

Comment: Not yet. Still waiting for a solution.

Comment: Did you find it yet ?

Comment: No, I haven't find anything for that.

Answer (score -2):

Can use [hasFullAccess](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiinputviewcontroller/2875763-hasfullaccess) method of UIInputViewController