# Allow full access to custom keyboard in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, uikeyboard

I'm writing a custom keyboard for iOS. My keyboard needs to be allowed full access. I put `"RequestsOpenAccess"` with the value `"YES"` in `info.Plist`. But I still can't choose to allow full access in the setting. What should I do?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25472388/how-to-check-the-allow-full-access-is-enabled-in-ios-8

Answer (score 9):

Put the following text in info.plist of the keyboard extension, under Information Property List:

```
<key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
<dict>
    <key>IsASCIICapable</key>
    <false/>
    <key>PrefersRightToLeft</key>
    <false/>
    <key>PrimaryLanguage</key>
    <string>en-US</string>
    <key>RequestsOpenAccess</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
<key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
<string>com.apple.keyboard-service</string>
<key>NSExtensionPrincipalClass</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).KeyboardViewController</string>
```

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem here.
I found out that all you have to do is to remove your app totally. Then reinstall it, and you can see "Allow Full Access" in the setting.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should set the "RequestsOpenAccess" to "YES" in your keyboard extension's info.plist file, not your container App's file.

Second, in your extension App info.plist file, set "RequestsOpenAccess" to "YES" under: NSExtension -> NSExtensionAttributes -> RequestsOpenAccess

Answer (score 1):

If you use SwiftUI project, then in Keyboard extension Info tab, you can expand the `NSExtension`, then set `YES` for `RequestsOpenAccess`

[image]