# Custom keyboard "Allow Full Access" issue for iOS 10?

Tags: ios, swift, ios10, custom-keyboard

This is something weird I have noticed that, **Custom keyboard** works well in **iOS 9** but if I open same app for **iOS 10** then it misbehave like first time keyboard is not open if "`Allow Full Access`" toggle is `OFF`, I need to switch toggle to `ON` and `OFF` to work without full access feature and also "`Allow Full Access`" detection code not working sometime.

I also noticed that some people raised [this](https://origin-discussions-us.apple.com/thread/7665636) issue on Apple developer forum, Seems it iOS 10 issue.

If anyone also facing same issue and found solution then please reply here.

Comment: Check this might be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39543113/allow-full-access-check-in-keyboards-ios10

Comment: Your solution here :- http://stackoverflow.com/a/39554347/3752143

Comment: perfect.... Above link have solution.