# Issue with custom keyboard with images

Tags: ios, keyboard, custom-keyboard, uipasteboard

I am working on iOS custom keyboard. In this I need to show stickers and gifs in the custom keyboard, I'm able to show the images on the keyboard, but the problem is, when user select an image from the keyboard I want to show it on the `textDocumentProxy`. After doing some research I understood that it's not possible to insert the images as the `textDocumentProxy.insertText`. So I tried `UIPasteboard`to copy the image from the keyboard and paste it into the input field [like this](http://o.aolcdn.com/hss/storage/midas/27c2fb5dfeccbf84ef00ce9e5197ac64/200746978/popkey.gif).

Here my code :

```
let pb = UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard()
let image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "1.png")!
let imgData: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!
pb.setData(imgData, forPasteboardType: kUTTypePNG as String)
pb.image = image
```

And I also set the `RequestsOpenAccess` to `true` in .plist file  and allowed access for the custom keyboard in the device as well. But it's not working for me.

Please suggest the possible ways to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When I selected the image in the keyboard it does not show that the image is copied or not. And same for the paste. It doesn't show the paste option either when I long press in an input view.

Comment: Please review this answer i hope solve your issue :- http://stackoverflow.com/a/39554347/3752143

Answer (score 0):

You want to use gif images in custom keyboard [link.](http://o.aolcdn.com/hss/storage/midas/27c2fb5dfeccbf84ef00ce9e5197ac64/200746978/popkey.gif)  and in above code you are using png image.

If you want to copy non gif image then you can use below code for Swift 3

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageview: UIImageView!
var img : UIImage = UIImage(named:"1.png")!
imageview = UIImageView(image: img)
//copy image code
UIPasteboard.general.image = imageview.image!
```

or If you want to use gif image then you can use below code for Swift 3

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "imagename", withExtension: ".gif")
let data: NSData = NSData(contentsOf: url!)!
UIPasteboard.general.setData(data as Data, forPasteboardType: "com.compuserve.gif")
```

Comment: could you please share the solution you got @Ramakrishna i am having same issue 
thanks