# How to properly check if user has enabled "Allow Full Access" to custom keyboard extension

Tags: ios, swift, permissions

I've tried prowling stackoverflow, and I've found some answers where you:

1) update `UIPasteboard`, which I don't want to be altering for obvious reasons ([Allow Full Access check in keyboards iOS10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39543113/allow-full-access-check-in-keyboards-ios10/39554347#39554347))

2) check `NSUserdefaults`,  drawbacks are the keyboard must be opened, and allow full access be enabled, and if it is later disabled, there will be the false value (https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/28690)

Looking for iOS 10, Swift 3 solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this is what I use in my code in swift

```
var hasAccess: Bool {
    get{
        if #available(iOSApplicationExtension 11.0, *) {
            return self.hasFullAccess
        } else {
            return UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor != nil
        }
    }
}
```